# Reveal Popup for foundation to show at bottom of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, modal-dialog, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to put my reveal popup to show at the center at the bottom part of my page, I was wondering if I should just adjust the top margin of the said div for it to go down. Currently the popup shows at in the center top part of the page.I also need it to work with regards to it being responsive, so I was wondering what should I put in my  CSS to make it go in the center of the page in all kinds of screen resolutions, not just with mobile screens but with different monitor sizes also.

```
.modalStyle{
border:none;
color:white;

text-align:center;
}

<div id="idModal" class="reveal-modal small modalStyle" data-reveal>
    <p>Some Text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Take a look at [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/). i use it in all of my projects for popups. You can use images, html content, ...